# Multiple RegEx pattern in Classic ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I am using Regex in classic ASP for validation purpose. I would like to validate two different values and check if only the listed characters and symbols mentioned in the two patterns are used for that values  and I have tried to use two different Regex objects for that. But that is not working for me

Here is my code

```
Set re = New RegExp
With re
  .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9\&_+()/-]"
  .Global = True
  .IgnoreCase = True
End With 

Set reNew  = New RegExp
With reNew
  .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9.!\"£$%^&()_+-=[]{}#:@./<>?\\|]"
  .Global = True
  .IgnoreCase = True
End With 

  if re.Test(strComments) = false   then
                    response.write " <label>Upload failed !! Please enter comments using valid characters a-z A-Z 0-9 \._+()%/&-</label>"
                    response.end  
                    else             
                          if reNew.Test(strremark) = false  then
                          response.write "<label> Upload failed !! Please enter remark using valid characters a-z A-Z 0-9 \._+()%/&-</label>"
                          response.end 
                          end if
  end if
```

Can anyone help me understand where i made a mistake ?

Comment: The second pattern has `+-=` which denotes a range. You could move the `-` to the end of the character class, and escape the square brackets in the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9.!\"£$%^&()_+=[\]{}#:@./<>?\\|-]`

Comment: Maybe try this: `[a-zA-Z0-9\&_+()\/-]|[a-zA-Z0-9.!""£$%^&()_+-=[\]{}#:@.\/<>?\\|]`. You were leaving some forward slashes un-escaped. You also had a single quote in your second regexp, which although you had escaped in the expression would still have thrown a VBscript syntax error. The `|` is the regexp equivalent of `OR`, so you can join both together. It also helps if you use a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test and analyze your expressions first. I'm not great at regexp, but you could certainly integrate the two expressions into one rather than using `|`.

Comment: Just saying "But that is not working for me" doesn't help us, what doesn't work?, is there an error, if so what is it? Be descriptive. The other point is why do you need two regex patterns, could they not be combined?

Comment: @user692942 i will keep that in mind thanks .... I used two regex patterns because I wanted to do two separate  sets of validations .

Comment: In which case it would have probably been cleaner to just adjust the pattern after each test instead of creating multiple regex instances.

Answer (score 0):

Fix with the following code:

```vb
Set re = New RegExp
With re
  .Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9&_+()/-]+$"
End With 

Set reNew  = New RegExp
With reNew
  .Pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!""£$%^&()_+=[\]{}#:@./<>?\\|-]+$"
End With
```

Double quotes must be doubled, hyphens must be used as last characters  inside brackets and the close bracket must be escaped also.

`\&` has an unnecessary backslash that I deleted.

Anchors are used to match the entire string, `+` ensuring matching one or more of allowed characters.

Do not set `.Global = True` and `.IgnoreCase = True`, these are redundant codes as both can be `False`.

Comment: thanks a lot .....but .... [a-zA-Z0-9\&_+()\/-]|[a-zA-Z0-9.!""£$%^&()_+-=[\]{}#:@.\/<>?\\|]  using this in the second pattern  worked for me

Comment: @TJ32 `[]` is closing the second expression prematurely. The expression is contained within square brackets, so if you include a closing square bracket within your expression, it will end it. You need to escape the closing square bracket: `[\]`, much like SQL injection, the backslash is telling the expression "yes, this is a closing tag, but it's part of the expression and NOT the expression syntax". Again, I'd recommend using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) before committing any changes to code.

Comment: @TJ32 I just fixed the expressions you had, I di not try to merge them into one. The merged one is `"^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9&_+()/-]+|[a-zA-Z0-9.!""£$%^&()_+=[\]{}#:@./<>?\\|-]+)$"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for multiple `RegExp` object instances, the only thing that changes is the pattern which is just a string, so store the string in a variable and replace the pattern before each `Test()`.

```vb
Dim stringToTest: stringToTest = "..." 'Your test string
Dim validationPattern1: validationPattern1 = "..."
Dim validationPattern2: validationPattern2 = "..."
Dim re: Set re = New RegExp
'Set regex properties
With re
    .Gloabl = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
End With
'Before testing add the pattern
re.Pattern = validationPattern1
If Not re.Test(stringtoTest) Then
    'Validation1 failure logic here
    '...
End If
'Add the next pattern
re.Pattern = validationPattern2
If Not re.Test(stringtoTest) Then
    'Validation2 failure logic here
    '...
End If
```